# Can't instal LibGDX

Tags: android, libgdx

I'm trying to install LibGDX on my mac. It asks for a reference to the android SDK which I downloaded from here:
http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=tools

But when I link to that directory, I get this error:
[image]

What do I do?

Comment: Did you move on to http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/adding-packages.html and add `Android SDK Build-tools Rev 23.0.1` ?

Comment: Are you sure that you want to develop android applications? If you don't want to, you could just uncheck the "Andorid" subproject in order to eliminate the problem. Otherwise you will have to install the missin android packages

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that you have not the necessary verision and just need to update it. Open SDK manager (it should be in you SDK directory or you should be able to launch it from eclipse/android studio I guess) and you will see:

[image]

check it and download - it will resolve the problem (you can also update SDK Tools).

Comment: You should probably specify where you can get the sdk manager. Also the newer Android studios (i believe 1.3+) use an internal sdk manager. So you will not get that interface from newer android studios (unless you click on this tiny little button, which is very hard to find)